# Where is Ernst Kummer's grave located?

Tags: 19th-century, mathematics, famous-people

Where is [Ernst Kummer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Kummer) buried?

He was a famous mathematician, he died in 1893.

I tried a search on the findagrave website, but there is no entry for his name. I also tried some ancestry and genealogy websites, but there is no entry of his grave.

Comment: In case you did not know this: If you register your account you may request a merger of accounts, so you can restore your reputation count/privileges…

Comment: I don't care about some accounts issue. I would like know the location of the grave of Ernst Kummer.

Comment: The gist of the second sentence I gathered from this question existing on this very page. But the first sentence may create some issues down the road: your old unregistered 'account' is now probably no longer pingable (you'll no longer get notified of comments or asnwers), and if a new answer is posted to your older posts made with that 'account', you will no longer be able to 'accept' any of those answers. Both issues hinder communication/interaction and may lower the attractiveness of other users here otherwise interested in answering your questions…

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Something like: … _"for_ other users" that should read… // Since you have read the explanation: You may flag existing comments as obsolete ("no longer needed") now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ernst Eduard Kummer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Eduard_Kummer) was buried in the [St. Jacobi Kirchhof](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St.-Jacobi-Kirchhof_I):

> Finally, on May 14, 1893, influenza swept him away in the midst of his loved ones. On a glorious sunny day in May, his mortal remains were lowered into the tomb in the Jacobikirchhof, around which all those who held him dear had gathered.
>
> — Vorstand der Berliner Mathematische Gesellschaft (eds): "Festschrift zur Feier des 100. Geburtstages Eduard Kummers; mit Briefen an seine Mutter und an Leopold Kronecker", B.G. Teubner: Leipzig, 1910. ([p36](https://archive.org/details/festschriftzurfe00kummuoft/page/36/mode/2up?q=1893), translated from German)

In lists about 'famous persons buried there', Kummer usually does not feature a spot.

Since the cemetery is located some distance from its church, another snippet from a obituary might give a clue as to why:

> On a beautiful sunny May day, when the lilacs were fragrant and the songbirds were rejoicing, his earthly remains were lowered into the tomb in the Jacobikirchhof near the Rollkruge, around which all had gathered who held him dear and worthy, and over which the wreathed flag of the mathematical society of the University of Berlin, which he had favored from its founding, was lowered.
>
> — E. Lampe: "Nachruf für Ernst Eduard Kummer", Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung 3, 13-28 (1892-1893), quoted from: Andre Weil (ed): "Ernst Eduard Kummer Collected Papers. Volume I.
> Contributions to Number Theory", Springer: Berlin, Heidelberg, New York, 1975. (p21) ([Same text as in this scan](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?PPN37721857X_0003))

The [Rollkrug](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollkrug) was a now demolished tavern and [the cemetery](https://evfbs.de/index.php?id=455) was made smaller a few times, especially for building a subway and roads, demolishing quite a few buildings and relocating thousands of graves.

So: His grave may not have received [Ehrengrab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrengrab)-status and *may* no longer exist?

Comment: See also [scan](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN37721857X_0003?pg=13&tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B17%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D) of E. Lampe's "Nachruf ..." courtesy of the Göttingen Digitization Center.